# How to choose variable type when setting Home Assistant states from AppDaemon?

Tags: smart-home, home-assistant, python

I have a calculated result from a Python/AppDaemon script running on Home Assistant. I want to display that calculated result on my HA/LoveLace dashboard, so I created a *sensor* from AppDaemon. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able select what variable type I want my state to be. Clearly HA distinguises between `float`, `string`, or `bool` internally. When you go to `history` some sensors are displayed as plots, and others as bar charts. Everything I create---even numeric data---shows up as a string. How do *I* set the variable type of my own *sensors*?

I am using this line in AppDaemon to (1) create, and (2) update my sensor.

`self.set_state('sensor.my_sensor_value', result)`

Comment: By no means an expert, but in a template you would use `is_state(sensor.my_sensor_value) | float` to convert/use as a float. You may be able to use that in AppDaemon